# Ruby on rails - javascript current locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How a javascript can get the current locale in ruby on rails application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are few ways how to do it, for example you can set locale variable in your view like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var locale = '<%= I18n.locale %>';
</script>
```

Of course, this is a global variable, so you should use a namespace.